# Animate Divs One Right After the Other with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

Im trying to animate multiple divs, fading in, one right after the other in sequence when the page loads. I also want to do it in reverse, fading out in sequence, when i click to go to another page. How do i go about setting this up in jquery?

Comment: Unless you want to frustrate your users, don't add any animation between them clicking a link and the next page load. MS transitions ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ) didn't take off for a reason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kind of hard to give you an example since there are so many ways to animate in jQuery, but here's a simple example.  Animating two `<div>`s, one after the other (on page load):

See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/p7MJv/

HTML:

```
<div id="animation-one">Hello!</div>
<div id="animation-two">Jquery Animate!</div>
```

CSS:

```
#animation-one,
#animation-two
{
    opacity:0;
    top: 30px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:#00CCCC;
    font-size:35pt;
    position:absolute;
}

#animation-one
{
    background-color:#CCCC33;
    top:130px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#animation-one").animate({
    opacity:1.0}, 700,
    function() {
        // Callback function: This is called when 'animation-one'
        // is finished.
        $("#animation-two").animate({
            opacity: 1.0
        }, 700);
    }
);
```

Here's what's happening:

- Two `<div>`s are on the page with CSS `opacity: 0`
- When the page is loaded, the `<div>` with id `animation-one` is animated over a period of 700 milliseconds from opacity 0 to opacity 1.
- After the `animation-one`s animation has finished, another `<div>` (with id `animation-two`) has an animation kicked off in a similar fashion.

---

Now, fading out the `<div>`s is similar.  I've assumed that your link just directs to another page, so I've suspended the following of that link until the animation is finished:

This assumes you have a link `<a>` with an id of `next-page`, but really it can be any selector:

HTML:

```
<a id="next-page" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#next-page").click(function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr("href");

    $("#animation-two").animate({
        opacity: 0}, 700,
        function() {
            // Callback function:  This is called when 'animation-two'
            // is finished.
            $("#animation-one").animate({
                opacity: 0}, 700,
                function() {
                    // Direct the user to the link's intended
                    // target.
                    window.location = href;
                });
    })
});
```

Here's what's happening:

- When the link with id `next-page` is clicked, a similar animation sequence as described above occurs, but in reverse.
- After the last animation occurs, the link is followed properly.

I think seeing the example in the link above should help.  Also, make sure and check out the docs for [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Hope that helps!

**Edit:** Adding a link to another example since the OP wants to animate multiple `<div>`s at once: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/n3GEB/.  This moves common code into functions and hopefully makes the example easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the jQuery animation functions take a callback as the final parameter. This function is called when the animation is complete. You would start animating the next DIV in this callback. Another option would be [fxQueues](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/fxqueues).

There is not a perfect way to reverse the animation when leaving the page. You could do it for links on your page by doing something along the lines of:

```
$("a").click(function()
{
    var target = $(this).href;
    // Do animation
    // In the final completion callback, do
    window.location.href = target;
});
```

(Note I don't guarantee this works, it is just pseudocode)

Comment: See this question for an example of the callback function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668104/jquery-queueing-animations

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using callbacks and queues.

Take a look at this:

[jQuery queue events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561346/jquery-queue-events)
http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Hope this is a point in the right direction for you.