# Animate Divs One Right After the Other with Jquery-pt 2

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Please view my previous question here:

[Animate Divs One Right After the Other with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456608/animate-divs-one-right-after-the-other-with-jquery/4456782#4456782)

View my second answer....

Can anyone tell me how to write my code correctly so that i can animate more than just 2 divs? Please give me an example of at least 4 divs if you can. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give them a common class, iterate over them [with `.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), and [use `.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/), multiplying the current index number of the iteration by the duration.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/jPeAp/

*html*

```
<div class="animation">Hello!</div>
<div class="animation">Jquery Animate!</div>
<div class="animation">Hello!</div>
<div class="animation">Jquery Animate!</div>
```

*js*

```
$('.animation').each(function( index ) {
    $(this).delay( index * 700 ).fadeIn();
});
```

This way it will automatically work for any number of elements.

In the loop, `index` will be `0, 1, 2, etc.`. So the delay will be `0, 700, 1400, etc`.

---

**EDIT:**

If you can't give the elements a common class, then just group the IDs into one [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

```
$('#animation1,#animation2,#animation3,#animation4').each(function( index ) {
    $(this).delay( index * 700 ).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: so what about if i have a bunch of totally different IDs then?

Comment: @WillingLearner: That's why you use a class instead of an ID. If for some reason you can't assign a class, then just create a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) with all the IDs. I'll update my answer to show how.

Comment: what if i wanted to reverse the animation on a button press?

Comment: @WillingLearner: It depends on what you mean by "reverse the animation". Do you mean fade them out from last to first? If so, you can `.get()` the Array of DOM elements, and `.reverse()` the order, then place them back in a jQuery object, and do the same as above. This doesn't reverse the order on the page. Just in the Array. [Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/jPeAp/1/)